# Proving there exists basis $B$ for $R^2$ such that $[T]_B = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I've been stumped by this question for the last 2 days, and couldn't figure how to prove it.

> $T:R^2 \to R^2$ is a linear transformation (T$\neq$0) that satisfies $T^2=2T$ and it is known that $T$ is not invertible.
> Prove that there exists some basis $B$ of $R^2$ such $[T]_B = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$

What I don't understand is, if $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}^2=2\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$, doesn't it mean that there will always exist some $B$ for whom their will be a some $T$ such that the requirements are still satisfied?

Thanks in advance :)

Edit:
I forgot to include that $T\neq0$.

Edit 2:
Unfortunately, I suppose we were meant to solve this question without eigenvalues and eigenvectors. I had this idea, but I don't know if its entirely correct.

If $T^2=2T$, then: $T^2-2T=0 \to T(T-2I)=0$. So for any $(x,y) \in R^2$,
$T(T-2I)(x,y)=0$. But because $T\neq0$ is given, then $T-2I=0$ must be true. which leads to: $T=2I$. However, because $T$ is noninvertible, the matrix $[T]_B$ can't be $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ (because it invertible). But there are two other similar matrices that satisfy the same requirements:
$[T]_B=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ and $[T]_C=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. And if for some basis $B=(b_1,b_2)$, the matching matrix is $[T]_B$, then for some other basis $C=(b_2,b_1)$ the matching matrix is $[T]_C$, and in anyway there is some basis whose matrix is $[T]_B$.

Is this line of thinking correct?

Comment: You are *given* $T$ (satisfying these 2 properties), you are not looking for some $T.$ What you must prove is the *existence of some appropriate $B$ for that $T.$* Hint: prove that these 2 properties imply that $0$ and $2$ are eigenvalues.

Comment: @AnneBauval as far as I understand (and I might be wrong), $T$ isn't defined by the matrix itself, but rather by the basis that is used for the matrix. Doesn't it mean there can be infinite bases (which implies infinite transformations)? Why can't it actually be any base of $R^2$? If you can elaborate more it would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: $T$ is not "defined". You are only given *any* $T$ among the many noninvertible linear $T$'s $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ such that $T\circ T=2T,$ and you are asked to prove that it is diagonalizable. The solution $B$ will be unique up to rescaling of the 2 vectors, e.g. if $B=(u,v)$ is a solution then $(\pi u, -10v)$ will be another one.

Comment: @EmanuelL Do you know the concepts of minimal polynomial and eigenvalues?
By the way, there is an error: $T=0$ satisfies the assumptions and no basis leads to this form for the matrix of the null endomorphism

Comment: @EmanuelL Your attempt in the edit is false: The algebra of endomorphisms is not an integral domain, and from $AB=0$, you can't conclude that $A$ or $B$ is zero. Hence, $T(T-2)=0$ does not imply $T=0$ or $T=2I$. What follows in your attempt does not really make sense to me

Comment: @Didier even if it is given that $T\neq0$? If $T\neq0$, and $T(T-2I)(x,y)=0$, then: $T((T-2I)(x,y))=0$. Suppose: $(T-2I)(x,y)=(a,b)$ Then $T(a,b)=0$. However, because not for every $(x,y)$, $T(x,y)=0$, and $T(a,b)=0$ stands, then $(a,b)=0$, which in turn means: $(T-2I)(x,y)=T(x,y)-2I(x,y)=0 \to T(x,y)=2(x,y)$. Thanks for responding! I'd like to know where I'd gone wrong.

Comment: Oh, I see it. It could be that $(a,b) \in kerT$ such that $(a,b)\neq(0,0)$. I'll give it some more thinking.

Comment: @EmanuelL You can't say anything as strong as what you said on an endomorphism from a polynomial identity. For instance, the matrix $M=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ satisfies $M^2=0$, but obviously, $M\neq 0$.

Comment: @Didier you are correct. I must admit, I had to receive 2 hints from a friend, but I managed to solve this question (commented under SV-97's answer). I highly appreciate you for taking your time to point out my mistakes. Thank you :)

Comment: Hi @EmanuelL. Glad it helped. Your proof in comments is very good! You should post it as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking the wrong way around: you're given $T$ and have to show that there's some basis such that the representation of $T$ with respect to that basis is the given matrix.

But the statement is actually wrong the way it's stated: consider the zero map $T \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, v \mapsto 0$. This is clearly linear, satisfies $T^2=0=2T$ and isn't invertible. Assume that there was a basis $e_1, e_2$ such that $[T]_B = \pmatrix{0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2}$ then $[T]_B [e_2]_B = \pmatrix{0 \\ 2}$; but $[T]_B [e_2]_B = [T e_2]_B = [0]_B = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0}$ which is a contradiction.

You thus have to assume that $T$ is of rank exactly 1 for this to be true.

How to prove that modified statement: let $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Then $T(Tv) = T^2v= 2 (Tv)$ so if $Tv$ isn't zero it's an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $2$. Since $T$ is of rank 1 there is some $v$ such that $Tv$ is nonzero. Pick that $Tv$ as one basis element and add some other one to complete the basis and you can show that the representation w.r.t. that basis is the one you're after.

Comment: Hello, and thanks for responding! Unfortunately, we haven't learned about eigen vectors, and are only going to learn them in the next chapter. I suppose we were meant to solve this question without using that.

Comment: @EmanuelL oh alright that's fine; you don't really need to use the eigenvector factoid here :) Maybe this helps (without giving the answer away directly): since $T$ is noninvertible and nonzero what can you say about the dimensions of the kernel and image of $T$? Can you use this knowledge in constructing a basis that has the desired property?

Comment: Thanks! It took me another 2 hints from a friend, but I managed to solve it. I proved that both $dim(ImT)=dim(ker T)=1$. If I choose, $b_1 \in kerT$ and $b_2 \in ImT$ such that for some $w \in V$ the following applies $T(w)=b_2$, then: $T(b_2)=T(T(w))=T^2(w)$, but $T^2=2T$, so: $T(b_2)=T^2(w)=2T(w)=2b_2$. And since $b_1 \in kerT$ obviously: $T(b_1)=0$. From there I could prove that they are linearly independent and thus are a basis. Thanks for responding :)

Comment: Looks good! I'm glad you managed to work it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $T\colon \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ be **any** endomorphism such that $T^2 = 2T$.
Let $P(X) = X^2 - 2X = X(X-2)$ and $\mu_T$ be the minimal polynomial of $T$.
By assumption, $P(T)=0$, and $\mu_T$ must divide $P$.
Three cases can occur:

1. $\mu_T(X) = X$.
   In this case, we have $0 = \mu_T(T) = T$.
   Hence $T=0$.
   In any basis $B$ of $\Bbb R^2$, we have
   $[T]_B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.
2. $\mu_T(X) = X-2$.
   In this case, we gave $0 = \mu_T(T) = T - 2I_2$.
   Hence, $T= 2I_2$, and in any basis $B$ of $\Bbb R^2$, we have
   $[T]_B = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$.
3. $\mu_T(X) = P(X)$.
   Since the roots of the minimal polynomial $\mu_T$ are precisely the eigenvalues of $T$, it follows that $T$ has two eigenvalues, $0$ and $2$.
   Let $e_0$ be an eigenvector of $T$ satifying $Te_0 = 0$, and let $e_2$ be an eigenvector of $T$ satisfying $Te_2 = 2e_2$.
   Let $B=(e_0,e_2)$.
   Then $B$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^2$, and we have
   $[T]_B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$.

Assume that $T\neq 0$ and that $T$ is not invertible.
Then cases $1$ and $2$ cannot occur.
It remains that we are in case $3$, which concludes the proof.

Comment: Hello, and sorry for the late response. Unfortunately, eigen vectors are in the next chapter of the book and we were tasked to solve this question with what we know so far. So I admit I don't fully understand this solution right now...

Comment: I've edited the post with a new line of thinking. I'd highly appreciate if you could give it a look and tell me if im in the correct direction. Thanks :)